# Is it correct to say "zip the front pocket of the back pack all the way to the end"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Your child was  trying to zip the front pocket of a back pack but he did it halfway as shown in the picture.

Is it correct to say "**zip the front pocket of the back pack all the way**" or "**zip the front pocket of the back pack all the way to the end, not halfway**"?

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine; the first one sounds a little better as there is something slightly unusual about using *end* in this way.

It's also common to use *zip* with *up*, even if it's not being zipped in an upward direction, so you could also say *zip it all the way up*.

Comment: Some native speakers suggest "zip it all the way shut / closed". Is it ok to say it?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that's good too.